# Django 1.6: Clear data in one table

Tags: python, database, django, models

I've a table name UGC and would like to clear all the data inside that table. I don't want to reset the entire app which would delete all the data in all the other models as well. Is it possible to clear only one single model? I also have South configured with my app, if that would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could [use raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) :

```
 cursor.execute(“DROP TABLE UGC”)
```

or you could just use the ORM directly inside a Django shell :

```
UGCModel.objects.all().delete()
```

That would erase the data (not the table, though), so you have to be careful :)

Another way (for completeness and to make use of South) would be to comment out the model in your models declaration, migrate and then put it back again (assuming there are no models with a reference to it.)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In the admin interface, you can go to the list page for that model, then you can select all models and use the `Delete selected ...` action at the top of the table.

Remember that, in whatever way you delete the data, foreign keys default to `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so any model with a foreign key to a model you want to delete will be deleted as well. The admin interface will give you a complete overview of models that will be deleted.

Comment: Nice to point out the cascade thing, but be careful with the admin deleted action : in case you have many (I mean many) objects, it would take quite a long time and use up resources unnecessarily.

Comment: @Ambroise Why is that? Does the deletion logging really hog resources?

Comment: I've tried to delete 80k objects this way once : the behaviour is to loop over all items and call model_instance.delete() for each, whereas the model manager's method Model.objects.delete() is a bulk delete (all at once). I'd recommend against this method as soon as you reach a thousand objects but it is a viable and convenient method otherwise.

Comment: @Ambroise The delete action calls the `delete()` method on the queryset, ever since Django 1.1. It does, however, iterate over the queryset and logs the deletion of each separate model instance. This iteration doesn't take nearly as much resources as separately deleting each object, but I can see how it might strain your system if the queryset is that large.

Comment: Hmm I misunderstood the waiting time (and the occasional, low-specs server, shutdown) then, my bad :) Thank you for the explaination !

Answer (score 0):

Faced such issues today with django 2.0.2 because i created my model with

```
class Front(models.Model):
    pass
```

and migrated it but when i later updated the model, i couldn't run
`python manage.py makemigrations` because it was saying

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'update' to front without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows 
with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

What was my solution?

1. I choose option 2 which is to quit
2. I commented out the troublesome model/table which is `Front` in my case
3. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` which deleted the troublesome table/model
4. I uncommented my model and ran `python manage.py makemigrations` again which recreated the table/model and finally
5. I migrated my changes with `python manage.py migrate` and everyhing was resolved!

**Note: Be careful with the above instruction cause it will delete all references/foreign keys to the table/model with `on_delete=models.CASCADE` which is the default!**

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.1.14

If you're interested in doing it on the command line, and you'll be doing this type of cleaning of your db frequently, I do this:

```
# project_name/app_name/management/commands/clear_test_models.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps

keep_models = ['KeepModel0', 'KeepModel1']

class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
        clear all in app_name app except listed in keep_models list
    """
    help = 'clear all models except those listed in keep_models list'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_app = apps.get_app_config('app_name')
        my_models = my_app.get_models()
        for model in my_models:
            if model.__name__ not in keep_models:
                model.objects.all().delete()
```

To run on the command line:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app_name.settings.local python manage.py clear_test_models
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Django shell:

```
>>> py manage.py shell
>>> from [your_app].models import [Your_Model] as md
>>> md.objects.all().delete()
>>> exit()
```

Remember to replace [your_app] with the app name and [Your_Model] with the name of the model you want to clear from the database.

Keep in mind this will remove the data in the table but not the table itself. If you wanted to do the latter you'd need to drop the table.